# Make Highcharts 'shared' tooltip color different from series color

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a multiple series highcharts **and a shared tooltip** and i am trying to set the tooltip border color of a series different from its series color. If i set it on the global tooltip object, it sets the color to all the series. So i tried setting the tooltip border color at the series level and it appears color attribute is not inherited into the series level from the global tooltip component. Need help.

Attaching my jsfiddle below -

In the fiddle i choose not to set the tooltip color so that highcharts sets the border color of the tool tip to the series color. But what i really need is the tooltip border color of the blue series to be red. Can that be accomplished?

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/arj_ary/5yjhfh9x/

**Global tooltip component -**

```
  tooltip: {
              shared: true,
              useHTML: true,
              crosshairs: {width:1, color:COLORS.gray_1, zIndex:3},
              borderColor: COLORS.black, //setting here would set it to black for both the series
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderRadius: 0,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .85)'
          }
```

**Series level :**

```
series.push({
                    type: 'spline',
                    color: COLORS.red_3,
                    data: [],
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false,
                            lineWidth: ChartSize[this.size].lineWidth,
                            halo: null
                        }
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        trackByArea:true,
                        shared: false,
                        useHTML: true,
                        borderColor: COLORS.red_3, //setting here does not work since we have a global tooltip color defined above.
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        crosshairs: {width:1, color:COLORS.gray_1, zIndex:3}
                    },

                    name: "series1",
                    zIndex: 3
                });
```

EDIT:-

Tried below code for a shared tooltip, haven't got it to work yet (It still sets the attribute to all the series and not just series1 which is desired in my case)

```
  HC.wrap(Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function(p, point, mouseEvent) {
        p.call(this, point, mouseEvent);

        if (point && point.length > 0 && point[0].series.name === 'series1') {
            var pointTooltipBorderColor = point && point.length > 0 &&  point[0].options.tooltip && point[0].options.tooltip.borderColor,
            seriesTooltipBorderColor = point && point.length > 0 && point[0].series && point[0].series.options.tooltip && point[0].series.options.tooltip.borderColor,
            borderColor = pointTooltipBorderColor || seriesTooltipBorderColor,
            label = this.label;

            if (label && borderColor) {
            label.attr({
                stroke: borderColor
            });
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Yes, with the formatter only the tooltip contents can be formatted, not the tooltip as a whole like its borderColor.

Comment: @morganfree I have a shared tooltip, so the answer in the link doe snot work for me. How can i make it work for a shared tooltip?